# How to call a method by Timer in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer

I have a method

MyClass.cs

```
 public class MyClass
 {

 public static void ShowPopup(System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl div)
  {
   //....
  }

}
```

I can call this method in Page_Load of a aspx.page

Page.aspx.cs

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


     MyClass.ShowPopup(div_main);


    }
```

But I need refresh this method every 15 seconds

I tried like this but Timer is not working !

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Web.UI.Timer tm = new System.Web.UI.Timer();
        tm.Interval = 15000;
        tm.Enabled = true;
        tm.Tick += tm_Tick;


    }

     void tm_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyClass.ShowPopup(div_main);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
     timer.Interval = 500;
     timer.Elapsed += tm_Tick;
     timer.Enabled = true;
}

void tm_Tick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyClass.ShowPopup(div_main);

    }
```